# Web Api Routing conflict

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

There is a web api config problem with the parameter types.
I need to recognize two type of parameters, one is `int` and other is `boolean`. In WebApi config default route is setted as `"api/{controller}/{id}"`, and when i parse integer it is OK, but i need also to parse boolean parameter.
So when I go to `/api/controller/1` url, i need it to go to the Action with `int` input parameter, and when I go to `/api/controller/{true|false}` url, I need it to go to Action where input is `boolean`.

Any solutions?
Thx

Comment: You can just use the `api/{controller}/{id:bool}` constraint, I believe. How does that work for you?

Comment: It redirects url ("api/{controller}/int|bool") to api/{controller } action

Answer (score 3):

Use `Route` or `RoutePrefix` filter attributes as mentioned in [Attribute Routing in Web Api 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and [Create a REST API with attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing).

Since I don't know the whole structure of your api controller and its methods, I can just put two examples for above attributes here. Generally, We place the `Route` attribute to filter requests related to a controller. In your question can be something like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/{controller}")]
```

And to filter specific requests for each method, we use `Route` attribute before each method, for example in your question it can be some thing like bellow line of code for a `boolean` input method:

```
[Route("{id:bool}")]
```

You need to know some rules to employ mentioned attributes as I placed 2 links.

Comment: Now it returns: "Multiple actions were found that match the request:..."

Comment: It doesent' work after edit, redirects it to  api/{controller } action. Can you provide with some more detailed example?

Comment: @HodzaNdzaho I completely changed the answer. please read 2 articles placed around this to be completely aware of your requirements.